# T-SQL statement with possible nulls on some results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables as follows:

Project

```
pid   pname   pdesc
-----------------------
 1    pr1     desc for pr1
 2    pr2     desc for pr2
```

Workitem

```
wid  pid*   wname   wdesc
---------------------------------
 1    2     wr1     desc for wr1
 2    2     wr2     desc for wr2
```

`pid` is a foreign key

I want to write a SQL statement where it searches for a specific string in these two tables. The statement should cover the following scenarios searching BOTH name and desc in BOTH tables:

If the user searches for `"wr1"` then the result should return the following:

```
wid: 1, pid: 2, wdesc: "desc for wr1",  pname: "pr2",  pdesc: "desc for pr2"
```

If the user searches for `"pr1"` then the result should be:

```
wid: null, pid: 1, wdesc: null,  pname: "pr1",  pdesc: "desc for pr1"
```

If the user searches for `"desc"` then the result should be:

```
wid: null, pid: 1, wdesc: null,  pname: "pr1",  pdesc: "desc for pr1"
wid: null, pid: 2, wdesc: null,  pname: "pr2",  pdesc: "desc for pr2"
wid: 1, pid: 2, wdesc: "desc for wr1",  pname: "pr2",  pdesc: "desc for pr2"
wid: 2, pid: 2, wdesc: "desc for wr2",  pname: "pr2",  pdesc: "desc for pr2"
```

I am thinking if I need to do two separate SELECT statements and then join them and group the result by pid. But wondering if there's a more efficient way..

Comment: What does this question have to do with [tag:sql-query-store]?

Comment: Why are you some your values delimited and others not? There are commas are `wid` and `pid`, but nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have, as your expected results, looks like malformed JSON. I'm going to **assume** that all the values should at least be comma separated. Then you can use SQL Server's in built `FOR JSON` functionality to achieve this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.Project (pid int, pname char(3), pdesc varchar(15));
INSERT INTO dbo.Project
VALUES(1,'pr1','desc for pr1'),
      (2,'pr2','desc for pr2');
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.WorkItem (wid int, pid int, wname char(3), wdesc varchar(15));
INSERT INTO dbo.WorkItem
VALUES(1,2,'wr1','desc for wr1'),
      (2,2,'wr2','desc for wr2');

GO

DECLARE @YourParam varchar(15) = 'pr1';

SELECT REPLACE(STUFF((SELECT WI.wid,P.pid,WI.wdesc,P.pname,P.pdesc
                      FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES),1,2,''),'}]','')
FROM dbo.Project P
     LEFT JOIN dbo.WorkItem WI ON P.pid = WI.pid
WHERE P.pdesc LIKE '%' + @YourParam + '%'
   OR WI.wdesc LIKE '%' + @YourParam + '%'; --Add the Name columns as needed.

GO

DROP TABLE dbo.Project
DROP TABLE dbo.WorkItem;
```

---

Edit: Based on the comments, perhaps this is what you are *really* after:

```sql
DECLARE @YourParam varchar(15) = 'desc';

SELECT REPLACE(STUFF((SELECT NULL AS wid,P.pid, NULL AS wdesc,P.pname,P.pdesc
                      FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES),1,2,''),'}]','')
FROM dbo.Project P
WHERE P.pdesc LIKE '%' + @YourParam + '%'
   OR P.pname LIKE '%' + @YourParam + '%'
UNION ALL
SELECT REPLACE(STUFF((SELECT WI.wid,P.pid,WI.wdesc,P.pname,P.pdesc
                      FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES),1,2,''),'}]','')
FROM dbo.Project P
     JOIN dbo.WorkItem WI ON P.pid = WI.pid
WHERE P.pdesc LIKE '%' + @YourParam + '%'
   OR WI.wdesc LIKE '%' + @YourParam + '%'
   OR P.pname LIKE '%' + @YourParam + '%'
   OR WI.wname LIKE '%' + @YourParam + '%';
```

Comment: This is very close but I have 2 asks.. is there a way of writing this without using JSON? Also your solution doesn't cover the last scenario as in it only returns 3 rows.

Comment: Yes, but I was ended up guessing what you *really* wanted after not getting responses to my [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66991272/t-sql-statement-with-possible-nulls-on-some-results#comment118415506_66991272), @SeanD .

Comment: As for why use `FOR JSON`, it keeps the code pretty succinct. Otherwise you'd need to `CONCAT` the values, conversions *and* `COALESCE`/`ISNULL`s to ensure that the `NULL` values were properly returned. It's, therefore, much easier to just use the `INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES` option for the JSON results and not have to worry about that. (Much less ugly than `COALESCE(CONVERT(varchar(12),WI.wid),'null')`.)

Answer (score 0):

Schema and insert statement:

```
 create table Project(pid int, pname varchar(50),   pdesc varchar(50))
 insert into Project values(1,    'pr1','desc for pr1');
 insert into Project values(2,    'pr2','desc for pr2');
 
 create table Workitem(wid int,  pid int,   wname   varchar(50), wdesc varchar(50));
 insert into Workitem values(1,    2,     'wr1'     ,'desc for wr1');
 insert into Workitem values(2,    2,     'wr2'     ,'desc for wr2');
```

Query:

```
 select concat('wid: ',w.wid, ' , pid: ',p.pid, ' , wdesc:',  w.wdesc,
 ' , pname: ',p.pname ,' , pdesc: ',p.pdesc) Output
 from 
 project p left join  workitem w on p.pid=w.pid
 where pdesc like '%desc%' or wdesc like '%desc%';
```

| Output |
| --- |
| wid: , pid: 1 , wdesc: , pname: pr1 , pdesc: desc for pr1 |
| wid: 1 , pid: 2 , wdesc:desc for wr1 , pname: pr2 , pdesc: desc for pr2 |
| wid: 2 , pid: 2 , wdesc:desc for wr2 , pname: pr2 , pdesc: desc for pr2 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=41465f7763679ea4b78a9af93c1b3ab9)*